# Export All Emails from Mac Mail.app as RTF file?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I have an email folder which has ~5 GB of emails in it.
In order to save space, I have exported it as a .mbox file.
Now I want to export each mail as a text or RTF file so that reading it becomes easy and so does searching.

Please give me a solution. I am ok with AppleScript or Shell.
I do not want to download an application for this.

Logic should be simple as this

1. Read specific folder from Mail.app.
2. Read Each Email.
3. Export each email to /Users/xyz/Desktop/.rtf or .rtfd.
4. Ignore the attachments, just the name of the attachment in the rtf is ok.

Comment: Well that makes it sound easy ...

Comment: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!